# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory

Tags: mysql, tomcat

I just started receiving this error today, on a Tomcat 8 installation. Possibly, the error started after updating Tomcat 8 to the latest version.

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory

Where do I find this class -- as in, what JAR is it in, and where do I get that jar?

My data source is set up exactly like the examples given in many Tomcat tutorials. Specifically, the factory is "org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory" and the driverClassName is "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver".

This was all working fine when I set it up a few weeks ago. Nothing changed other than possibly I did a "yum update" earlier today.

Comment: I should add that I am not using any kind of dependency management tool. I am deploying the JAR files I need myself. Therefore, what I need is a direct reference to the JAR file that I can download, not a command to put in a build script. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/t/Downloadtomcatdbcp800rc1jar.htm) for version 8.
I also have [this link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-dbcp/7.0.30) on my notes for version 7.